# How to preselect a value with special character on Radio List with URL variable query

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, radiobuttonlist, encodeuricomponent

I am trying to add the autofill or pre-populate feature to a Wordpress form using URL Query Variable but I am having problem when the value from a **RADIO LIST** that I want to pre-select contains special characters, specifically spacebar, parenthesis, period, and forward slash. Below is my code for the radio list:

```
var specified = ( getQueryVariable("specified") != false ) ? 
decodeURI(getQueryVariable("specified")) : '';

if ( specified != false && $('input[name=school]').length > 0 ) {
  $('input[name=school][value=' + specified + ']')
  .prop('checked', true);
  }
```

For example, if I want to pre-select my radio list item "United States", simply having URL input of "www.mydomain.com/?specified=United%20States?"

All other field types in the form work fine with the UTF-8 characters.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What values are in the radio list?

Comment: The values are a list of countries where the schools are. For example, "Germany", "France", "South Africa". And the form will preselect "Germany" and "France", for instance, but won't preselect "South Africa" even when the space bar is represented by %20.